Can I edit the EWKB format to use only 4 bytes for coordinate values instead of 8 bytes in PostGIS?
I am using PostgreSQL with PostGIS to store a large amount of polygons. I want to minimize the space my polygons are taking up in my database and since all the coordinate values of the polygons I am working with only need to be 32 bit integers, I could definitely save space if the EWKB format that PostGIS uses for storage could be shortened down to use 32-bit integers instead of the 64-bit doubles for each coordinate value. Here is where I found the code for the format: https://libgeos.org/specifications/wkb/#extended-wkb
(GEOS is apparently a core dependency of PostGIS)
Is it possible for me to go in and edit the few lines of code that currently define doubles to define 32-bit integers instead? If it's possible, how would I be able to access the details of the datatype in order to change it?
Also, when I asked ChatGPT about this, it said I would have to create a custom format and convert things from the standard EWKB to my EWKB format. Is that the only solution or is there a way I can just customize my database so that it only stores coordinate values in 32 bit integers?
I have found the GEOS library linked above which details the EWKB format, and I also know that there's an ALTER TYPE command in PostgreSQL, but I'm not sure how to go about altering such a specific part of the geometry datatype / the geometry storage format (EWKB)...
Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

I would read this Geometry Data type. Relevant points: Including all geometry information allows PostGIS to use EWKB as the format of record (e.g. in DUMP files). and EWKB and EWKT are used for the "canonical forms" of PostGIS data objects.. I'm going to say altering the type would not end well.
